# Remote Stream Server from IceCast

Tags: icecast

I an trying to reproduce a video streaming in an IceCast server so I would like to configure it in icecast.xml server. I have the following questions:

1. In the mount section how can I configure the video stream for reading the input.I would like to read a stream of the following type:

> rtsp://*******************/Streaming/Channels/101?transportmode=unicast

In fact, I have just configured the following iceCast.xml file:

```
<icecast>
    <limits>
        <clients>1000</clients>
        <sources>42</sources>
        <threadpool>5</threadpool>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>
    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>hackme</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>hackme</relay-password>
        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
        <admin-password>hackme</admin-password>
    </authentication>
    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
    </listen-socket>
    <relay>
        <server>rtsp://172.31.8.44/Streaming/Channels/101?transportmode=unicast</server>
        <port>8000</port>
        <mount>/test.ogg</mount>
        <on-demand>0</on-demand>
        <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
    <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/test.ogg</mount-name>
        <username>othersource</username>
        <password>hackmemore</password>
        <max-listeners>1</max-listeners>
        <dump-file>/test.mp4</dump-file>
        <burst-size>65536</burst-size>
        <fallback-mount>/etc/icecast2/test.mp4</fallback-mount>
        <fallback-override>1</fallback-override>
        <fallback-when-full>1</fallback-when-full>
        <intro>/etc/icecast2/videoDAT.mp4</intro>
        <hidden>1</hidden>
        <no-yp>1</no-yp>
        <stream-url>rtsp://172.31.8.44/Streaming/Channels/101?transportmode=unicast</stream-url>
        <on-connect>sh /home/stream-start.sh</on-connect>
    </mount>
    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <basedir>/usr/share/icecast2</basedir>
        <logdir>/var/log/icecast2</logdir>
        <webroot>/usr/share/icecast2/web</webroot>
        <adminroot>/usr/share/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
        <alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <loglevel>3</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <chroot>0</chroot>
    </security>
</icecast>
```

2. How could I configure it for reading a mp4 file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icecast can't relay RTSP streams.  You can only relay compatible HTTP Progressive streams (which are the streams servers like Icecast and SHOUTcast serve.)

Icecast also will not decode your MP4.

You need to use a tool like FFmpeg to relay to Icecast.  Something like...

```
ffmpeg -i <your RTSP URL> icecast://example.com/stream
```

Comment: I have defined the following mountPoint in the icecast.xml project:       <mount type="normal">
        <mount-name>/data.ogg</mount-name>.....
        <on-connect>sh /bin/stream-start.sh</on-connect>
    </mount>..... and defined a stream.sh script in /bin/stream-start.sh . It is supposed that when http://..../data.ogg request is executed the stream-start.sh must be executed but is not executed. I have now the following questions: 1- How must the on-connect script be defined (/bin/stream-start or /bin/stream-start.sh) 2- how can you pass parameters to the starting script.

Comment: @GorkaSanzMonllor Post a new question.